# WLAN-Connection is terminated

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.10

I use Ubuntu 20.10 with a desktop PC and WLAN. My WLAN card is Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter. The driver is `ath9k`. Unfortunately, Internet access breaks down regularly. Can anyone help me further? Many thanks in advance.
Christian

Comment: There can be a ton of reasons for that. It is impossible to tell. Most likely it is unrelated to Ubuntu, because these adapters are perfectly supported.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will give it a try next time, the access breaks down.